# classes - make parent changes affect children

Tags: python

I'm trying to represent a binary tree using class. Here's what i've got:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, cargo, parent=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.parent = parent
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.path = ''

    def giveChild(self, child, sub):
        child.parent = self.cargo
        if sub == 'left':
            self.left = child
            child.path += 'l'
        if sub == 'right':
            self.right = child
            child.path += 'r'
```

I use `path` to store a path from a root to a certain leaf like 'llrlr' (left-left-right-left-right). 
When I add new nodes to a tree, I go from bottom-to-top. First I create leaves, then I give them a parent node.
Ok, now I create two leaves:

```
r = Tree('r')
p = Tree('p')
```

The I create the next node, which is a parent for **r** and **p**:

```
rp = Tree('rp')
rp.giveChild(r, 'left')
```

Now since **r** is a left node of **rp**, **r**'s path becomes 'l'.
The problem is how to change **r**'s path when **rp** gets a parent node? My codes doesn't change the path to **'...ll'** or **'...rl'**, it's still just **'l'**.

Comment: This is a backwards way of creating a tree. There is no reason to create a tree from the bottom up. You might be able to update it using recursion from the parent back down to the children, adding a letter each time you go deeper and adding an `'r'` or an `'l'` depending on the child.

Comment: You could also make `path` a `property` and have it calculated every time.

Comment: What task are you using this tree for? Why does it even need that `path` attribute?

Comment: @PM2Ring for Huffman coding. The path is the code for a letter, like 1011 (i'm not gonna use l's and r's - that was just for example)

Comment: Ok. The usual way is to build the tree from the top down, and then create the codes by traversing the tree. There are some good answers already that show how to do this, and I suggest you take a look at them. But please read all the answers and comments: there are subtle bugs in at least one of the accepted answers that are corrected in a later answer.